# Birational equivalence of two curves on the projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ be a projective plane over some algebraically closed field. Suppose $C_{1}$ denote a curve defined by $y$ and $C_{2}$ be a curve defined by $y^{2}z-x^{3}$, where $[x:y:z]$ denotes a point in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$. How can I show that the bijective equivalence between $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$?

I tried to solve the question by constructing a rational map
 $$f: C_{1} \to C_{2} \textrm{ by }[x:0:1] \mapsto [x^{2}: x^{3}:1]  \textrm{ and } g: C_{2} \to C_{1} \textrm{ by } [x:y:1] \mapsto \left[\frac{y}{x}:0:1 \right].$$

And it works for one way; which is $g\circ f =1_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}$, an identity function. However, I failed to show that $f \circ g = 1_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}$. I think 
$$f \circ g ([a:b:1])= \left[\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}: \frac{a^{3}}{b^{3}}:1\right], $$
which is a little bit suspcious to say that it is identity.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Birational equivalence is weaker than isomorphism. You only require isomorphism of dense open sets. Your $f\circ g$ fails at one point, but that doesn't matter for birational equivalence.

Comment: You are mixing up $C_1$ and $C _2$ in your definitions of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes I know, but $\left[\frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}}: \frac{a^{3}}{b^{3}}:1 \right]$ seems not to the same as $[a:b:1]$ in general $a,b$, even if $b\neq 0$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Oh I see, I fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg   Oh thank you very much!, now it's clear!

Comment: The way you write your **rational** maps is wrong. You should write $f(x:0:z)=(x^2z:x^3:z^3)$ and $g(u:v:w)=(v:0:u)$ [This comment was written before the OP's last comment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact we have $$f\circ g([a:b:1])=\left[\frac{b^2}{a^2},\frac{b^3}{a^3},1\right]$$
On the domain of $f\circ g$ (i.e. on $C_2$) we have $a^3=b^2$. It follows that $b^2/a^2=a,b^3/a^3=b$.